# Picasso not loading url into ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, picasso

I am using Picasso to load image from url but it doesn't load the image from the url although i made some changes to the url as it contains Arabic characters

MainActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorAccent"
tools:context="com.alpha25.gridview.HomeActivity">



<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Load Image"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/load"/>
```

and this is my code at mainactivity.java

```
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    load = (Button)findViewById(R.id.load);
    String url = "https://arabian-chemistry.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%AA%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B6%D9%8A%D8%A9.png";

    load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            String encodeUriString = Uri.encode(uri.getLastPathSegment());
            String uriString = uri.toString().replace(uri.getLastPathSegment(), encodeUriString);
            Log.d("Taggggggg", uriString);
            Picasso.with(mContext).load(uriString).into(imageView);




        }
    });
```

Comment: can you check your logs. Is there any error?

Comment: No errors in the logs

Comment: Brother there is no problem with your code, and nor with your url. Just check for INTERNET permission.

Comment: or for check use ".error()" for placeholder in case of error. it will clarify that there is no error.

Comment: I gave the internet PERMISSION

Comment: load directly **URL** instead of uri

Answer (score 2):

```
Picasso.with(context)
            .load("https://arabian-chemistry.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%AA%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B6%D9%8A%D8%A9.png")
            .into(image);
```

Try this, Worked for me.

Comment: I gave the internet PERMISSION and made this , not working

Comment: In your code you are encoding that url. Are you doing same with answer?? Don't encode URL to URI, simply pass url as it is.

Comment: You can set listeners using Picasso for success and failure.Implement those listeners you will get the cause of failure.

Comment: please, could you build an apk from your project and the send it to me, I wanna see if the problem coming from the emulator or my device... my email: muhammadnoamany@gmail.com @pallavitapkir

Answer (score 0):

Try this change :-

```
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    load = (Button)findViewById(R.id.load);
    String url = "https://arabian-chemistry.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%AA%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B6%D9%8A%D8%A9.png";

    load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(url).into(imageView);
```

Comment: Use this like this :- Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load("https://arabian-chemistry.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%AA%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B6%D9%8A%D8%A9.png").into(imageView);

Comment: have you give permission of INTERNET in Android manifest file ? because it is working in my phone.

Comment: I gave the internet PERMISSION

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
String url =
    "https://arabian-chemistry.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%AA%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B6%D9%8A%D8%A9.png";

Picasso.with(mContext).load(url).into(imageView);
```

just these codes in my demo, worked for me.
don't forget permission of INTERNET.

Comment: also not working with me, could you show me your build.gradle file

Comment: please, could you build an apk from your project and the send it to me, I wanna see if the problem coming from the emulator or my device... my email: muhammadnoamany@gmail.com